# XPath 3.0 compare dates diffrence with duration literal

Tags: xml, date, xpath, xpath-3.0

Given XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <c cid="0"> 
        <d did="c0d0" d1="2015-02-11" d2="2015-06-15" />
        <d did="c0d1" d1="2015-04-01" d2="2015-04-14" />
    </c>
    <c cid="1"> 
        <d did="c1d0" d1="2014-11-15" d2="2015-07-21" />
        <d did="c1d1" d1="2016-02-10" d2="2016-02-25" />
    </c>    
</root>
```

Using XPath 3.0 I have to find all `c` nodes, which has at least one `d` child node, which `d2-d1` attributes values difference is less or equal 30 days. `d1` and `d2` values are dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
I've tried XPath:

`/root/c[d/xs:date(@d2)-d/xs:date(@d1)<=30]`

but I've got and error:

`Cannot compare xs:dayTimeDuration to xs:integer`

I use `XPath Builder` in `XPath 3.0` mode in `Oxygen XML Editor v18`. 
I suppose that this error is due to incorrect time duration setting. Please advice how to specify time duration as literal in XPath 3.0.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substract dates but then you get a dayTimeDuration and you need to compare to such a value: `/root/c[d[xs:date(@d2)-xs:date(@d1) <= xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')]]`.

Comment: And for the benefit of others, there's nothing here that needs XPath 3.0 - everything you need is in 2.0.